# my code give my this errore after call it takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, class, call

```
class Samadateconverter:
    def __init__(self, y , m , d ):
        self.y = y
        self.m = m
        self.d = d
                 
    def gregorian_to_hijri(self):
        # Calculate the Julian Day Number (JDN) for the Gregorian date
        jdn = int((1461 * (self.y + 4800 + int((self.m - 14) / 12))) / 4) + int((367 * (self.m - 2 - 12 * int((self.m - 14) / 12))) / 12) - int((3 * int((self.y + 4900 + int((self.m - 14) / 12)) / 100)) / 4) + self.d - 32075

        # Calculate the Hijri calendar date from the JDN
        h = int((jdn - 1948440 + 10632) / 10631)
        year = int((h + 10307) / 1335)
        month = ((h - 1) % 12) + 1
        day = jdn - 1948440 - int((year * 354) + int((3 + (11 * year)) / 30)) - int((month - 1) * 29.5) + 1

        return (year, month, day)
```

and then in another file i call it

```
from class_converter import Samadateconverter

Samadateconverter.gregorian_to_hijri(1233,5,7)
```

and its gave my this errore  gregorian_to_hijri() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: your function is expecting one argument and you are passing 3 (1233,5,7).

Comment: Given your design, you need `x = Samadateconverter(1233,5,7).gregorian_to_hijri()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of your class before then call your method:

```
conv = Samadateconverter(1233,5,7)  # This calls the constructor __init__
year, month, day = conv.gregorian_to_hijri()  # This calls your method
```

Output:

```
>>> year, month, day
(7, 9, 220376)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is defined as only taking one parameter: `self`

`self` is automatically passed in when `gregorian_to_hijri()` is called on an instance of your `Samadateconverter` object. When doing that, giving the function any arguments at all will result in this error.
If I am reading this right, you want your `Samadateconverter` object to hold values:

```
self.y = 1233
self.m = 5
self.d = 7
```

You should change your code to be:

```
from class_converter import Samadateconverter

converter = Samadateconverter(1233,5,7)
year, month, day = converter.gregorian_to_hijri()
```

Comment: Apologies, let me fix that

Edit: fixed as per deleted commenter's corrections

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
from class_converter import Samadateconverter

s = Samadateconverter(1233,5,7)
year, month, day = s.gregorian_to_hijri()
```